# KendoUI generate scripts but not run them

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid that has a column with dropdown list, to change some statuses. It will generate grid, generate input for dropdown and scripts under the input field, but they will somehow not proceed.

When I copy those scripts and run them in console, dropdown will start working.

Here is a grid column with that dropdown:

```
columns.Bound(update => update.FlowStatus)
        .Width(80)
        .Title("Status")
        .Encoded(true)
        //.ClientTemplate("<input class='dropDownStatus' data-value='#= FlowStatus #' data-id='#= Id #' />");
        .ClientTemplate(
            Html.Partial("FlowStatusesEditor", "statusDropDown" + "#=Id#").ToHtmlString()
        );
```

And a partial view that I'm using

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
@model String

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name(Model)
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Read(read => read.Action
                    ("GetFlowStatuses", "Update")
                )
            )
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .ToClientTemplate()
)
```

Any idea what to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `kendo.template` function for that.
Change your column client template like this

```
.ClientTemplate("#= flowStatusTemplate(flowStatus) #");

<script>
var flowStatusTemplate = kendo.template('@Html.Partial("FlowStatusesEditor", "statusDropDown" + "#=Id#").ToHtmlString()');
</script>
```

or you can move your partial page into scrip template like this

```
<script id="tmpFlowStatus" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("FlowStatus")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Read(read => read.Action
                    ("GetFlowStatuses", "Update")
                )
            )
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
```

and change the script like this

```
<script>
var flowStatusTemplate = kendo.template($("#tmpFlowStatus").html());
</script>
```

Comment: How does it work? It's trying to give me that widget code there, but it throws JavaScript critical error at line 92, column 177 in http://localhost:60603/Update\n\nSCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant

Comment: I can't debug your end here.. try move that partial page into same page. I'll updated my answer

Comment: It will generate this, just minified:https://jsfiddle.net/Lp0hq7tm/ which is not valid javascript.

Comment: Now after moving partial page into script template it throws some error with replace in kendo.all.min.js, that it can't replace null or undefined.

Comment: try to use another widget see if its running without error.

Comment: Yep, its doing with combobox also.